# Tooltip text goes out of tooltip when zoom-in

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Am using highcharts (Bar Graph) in my project and seems like whenever I zoom-in the text inside the tooltip I misalgined..

Drag the graph down or up in order to zoom-in.

Am using the v2.3.3 version of highcharts.

Here is some screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Comment: 2.3.3 is really old version. I advice to upgrade to 3.0.7.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade your highcharts to Latest version 3 solve this problem.Because this is bug in old version

Or

Write position of tooltip manually

```
tooltip: {
   positioner: 
      function(boxWidth, boxHeight, point) {         
         return {x:point.plotX + 20, y:point.plotY - 20
      };         
   }
}
```

Comment: hi sridhar,

is there any other alternative for this ?? upgrading might take me time for me coz of approvals.

Comment: adding positioning will move the tooltip around the x and y axis. but when zoom-in i can still reproduce it the same way.. Basically , the text is moving out of tooltip